# Inflate 2 layouts in one Fragment to update TextView - android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, item-decoration

I am trying to update a TextView with text in a method. The primary function of the method is to inflate a layout with a RecyclerView and to update these views with values from firestore. My RecyclerView also has an ItemDecoration attached which has its own layout. In this method I also want to update the textview of this layout. I tried creating a seperate View and inflating the ItemDecoration layout, finding the TextView and updating the text but the text doesnt update when run.

**OnCreate Method**

```
 public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.galway_fragment, container, false);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.galway_recycler);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(placeNames);

        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(HeaderDecoration.with(recyclerView)
                .inflate(R.layout.stamp_header)
                .parallax(0.2f)
                .dropShadowDp(4)
                .build());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        db.collection("galway")
                .get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            placeNames.add(document.getData().get("Name").toString());
                        }
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });
        View v2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.stamp_header, container, false);
        TextView header = (TextView) v2.findViewById(R.id.header);
        Log.i("HEADER", header.toString());
        header.setText("GALWAY");

        return v;
    }
```

*galway_fragment* is the RecyclerView layout which defines the layout for the fireStore data, *placeNames*. The ItemDecoration layout is defined by *stamp_header* which I am trying to set "GALWAY" in a TextView as a test.

**galway_fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/galway_recycler"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**stamp_header**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/red"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:text="HI THERE" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Stamp_header is the second layout i want to update Text. Thankful for any help!!

Comment: Is the `HeaderDecoration` your custom class?

Comment: @Gralls Yes, got from here: https://github.com/bleeding182/recyclerviewItemDecorations/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/github/bleeding182/recyclerviewdecorations/HeaderDecoration.java

Comment: I'm not pretty sure if decorators would be the best option for you. Wouldn't it be better to extend the list item layout so it will contain header?
But if you want to try, my first thought is to save the instance of this decorator. Add some method `setHeaderText` and update TextView from inside of `HeaderDecoration`, but honestly, I have no idea if it has a chance to work :D

Comment: @Gralls Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that but I'm pretty sure you can't add a heading easily with RecyclerView. You could with the older ListView